# How to organise placed orders

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

So when I place an order it creates a new order for every item in the cart. Lets say that I have 3 phones in my cart, then It would go to the database as as 3 orders. How would I go about it if I want to make it so these 3 phones would display as 1 order in "My orders"?

Here's my models:

```
class Order(TimestampMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), unique=False )
    phone_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('phone.id'),  
                         unique=False, nullable=True)
    accessory_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('accessory.id'),  
                             unique=False, nullable=True)
```

That's code for displaying:

```
@phones.route("/myorders", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def myorder():
    orders = Order.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.get_id())
    return render_template('phones/myorder.html', orders=orders)
```

and HTML:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block app_content %}
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="content-section">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      {% for order in orders %}
      <tr><th>{{order.id}} {{order.created_at}}</th>
      <tr>
      {% if order.phone %}
      <td>{{order.phone.brand.name}} {{order.phone.model}} </td> 
      {% endif %}
      {% if order.accessory %}
      <td>{{order.accessory.brand}} {{order.accessory.compability.platform}} {{order.accessory.type.type_of_accessory}} </td> 
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

How it looks on the page:

[image: order]

Code for creating an order:

```
@phones.route("/order/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def order():
list_of_phones = session['cart']
list_of_accessories = session['cart2']
for pid in list_of_phones:
    phone = Phone.query.get(pid)
    phone.stock = phone.stock - 1
    order = Order(
        user_id = current_user.get_id(),
        phone_id = phone.id)
    db.session.add(order)
    db.session.commit()

for aid in list_of_accessories:
    accessory = Accessory.query.get(aid)
    accessory.stock = accessory.stock - 1
    order = Order(
        user_id = current_user.get_id(),
        accessory_id = accessory.id)
    db.session.add(order)
    db.session.commit()

session.pop('cart')
session.pop('cart2')
flash('Order was added successfully', 'success')
return redirect(url_for('phones.shopping_cart'))
```

Difference after changes:

[image]

I modified code for displaying all orders:

```
@phones.route("/myorders", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def myorder():
# orders = Order.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.get_id())
orders = db.session.query(Order).filter_by(user_id = current_user.id).group_by(Order.order_id).all()
print(orders)
return render_template('phones/myorder.html', orders=orders)
```

And it kind of works, because it only display one order_id, but on the other side it only displays one item, see below:

[image]

Comment: Isn't this much more a template thing, on how you want to present it to a user on your web page? If yes, start with creating a mock-up of what you want it to look like. If you post that here, we might be able to help changing your template.

Comment: I just want the items that were ordered at the same time( as you can see on the picture 1 and 2 are from the same cart as well as  3,4 and 5) to display for the user as one order, so let's say that the user ordered 2 items and it would show as 1 order containing 2 items instead of 2 orders for 1 item each

Comment: Do you think timestamp is the way to go? it could easiliy happen that they differ like 14:24:24.999 and 14:24:25.011. Based on what would you say they belong to the same order?

Comment: Yes they would belong to the same order

Comment: That is not an answer to my question ;).

Comment: In my opinion I would go with the timestamp, that would be the easiest way. Not sure if that slight difference in time will be an obstacle

Comment: Question is, what time difference would be acceptable, and would that also mean any risc that you combine products into 1 order when they should not be? I would suggest adding a field to db table with an order_id or something similar to have a safe way of indicating this and this gives a nice way to show orders in your template.

Comment: I think that accuracy to the seconds should be enough. What would I store in that new field?

Comment: I would store a unique order id in that field. Timestamp of commits is not accurate, you cannot rely on that 1 second. You are purely relyong on db performance, concurrent actions, read/write, nr of items in cart. Who knows what time difference there will be when you have 100 items. But enough from me about this, I've made my point ;).

Comment: What would be the difference between field id and order_id then?

Comment: The id field auto increment, the order_id could be something you choose it to be. For instance to identify multiple products to the same order.

Comment: How I can make it so it gives the same value for few items?The number in order_id would have to increase +1 every order as well

Comment: I have added the code for creating an order on top

Comment: No, you don't want an auto-increment order_id. For instance you could generate a unique string or int as order_id and add that in your for aid loop, for every item that belongs to the same order. Add the new column to your class model first of course.

Comment: How I can create unique string or int? If i add a line of code in the loop pid `order_id=1` and the same for the loop aid, what should I add so for the next order it would be a different number or string (lets say second order would be 1+1, second 1+2)

Answer (score 1):

I tested this code, it works and groups order by randomly generated order_id:

```
@phones.route("/order/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def order():
    list_of_phones = session['cart']    
    random_string = random_generator()
    for pid in list_of_phones:
        phone = Phone.query.get(pid)
        phone.stock = phone.stock - 1
        order = Order(
            user_id = current_user.get_id(),
            phone_id = phone.id)
            order_id = random_string
        db.session.add(order)
        db.session.commit()

    session.pop('cart')
    flash('Order was added successfully', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('phones.shopping_cart'))

def random_generator():
    size = 16
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits 
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
```

in your app route:

```
@phones.route("/myorders", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def myorder():
    orders = db.session.query(Order).filter_by(
        user_id = current_user.id).all()

    return render_template('phones/myorder.html', 
        orders=orders)
```

In your template, you can use something like the following:

```
{% for order_id, order in orders | groupby('order_id') %}
    {{ order_id }}
    {% for i in order %}
        <ul>
          {{ i.id }}
          {{ i.phone_name }}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

with some test data I added to database, I get the following

```
abc

    1 phone1 
    2 phone2 
    3 phone3 


xyz

    4 phone4 
    5 phone5 
    6 phone6
```

Comment: there is some problem with the random generator, first I got an error `NameError: name 'string' is not defined`, then I have changed the string for str and got `AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'ascii_letters'`

Comment: Oops, missing imports. I added them to my answer.

Comment: Ok, so adding orders works and they got the same order_id if they are from the same cart, but when I add `| groupby('order_id')` nothing is displaying

Comment: check editted answer, take this line:     {% for order_id, order in orders | groupby('order_id') %}

Comment: still the same thing

Comment: Kind of trial and error to find the right way again. Is has been a while. Please see revised answer, just add this last line in your code. Don't forget to rename your variables from order.foo to i.foo in this example and also don't forget to close the for loop in template.

Comment: I added a picture after changing the html. the items are different than the ones from the previous picture, but that doesn't really matter.  The outcome is still pretty much the same as before. I think I would have to merge all orders with the same order_id and display as one.

Comment: I modified code the query and it displays one order_id, but only one item, any suggestions? You can check it in my post

Comment: Ok it works! Thank you very much, I have got one more question, is it possible to display a date next to the {{ order_id }}? I would like to use this format `created_at.strftime("%b-%Y - %H:%M")`, but when I put `i.created_at.strftime("%b-%Y - %H:%M")` it displays date for every item, I would like the date to display only once for every order

Comment: yeah, well that's not really possible with this set-up. The date can differ, while the order_id is the same for multiple products in the cart. You are only grouping items based on a column. To meet your needs, you could save order-id in a seperate table, add foreign key to order table and add only 1 order create date per order instead of per product. Then, write a query to get order_id with corresponding items from order table. But that's a whole different question.